# create a smooth bar beamer

Tags: beamer

I would like to create a smoothbar in my presentation. I am not using a defined theme but another one created by myself. Nevertheless, I didn't know how I can add a smooth bar inside. I would like to get one as in this figure. 
Any idea about the code needed to be add in my sty or.tex folder to create it? 
[image]

Here is the code of the theme created:

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
    \ProvidesPackage{beamerthemefemto}[2012/06/05 beamer theme femto package]
\RequirePackage{times}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%      _         _             _                     _                     
%  ___| |_ _   _| | ___    ___| |_    ___ ___  _   _| | ___ _   _ _ __ ___ 
% / __| __| | | | |/ _ \  / _ \ __|  / __/ _ \| | | | |/ _ \ | | | '__/ __|
% \__ \ |_| |_| | |  __/ |  __/ |_  | (_| (_) | |_| | |  __/ |_| | |  \__ \
% |___/\__|\__, |_|\___|  \___|\__|  \___\___/ \__,_|_|\___|\__,_|_|  |___/
%          |___/                                                           
%

% commande permettant de dessiner une page de fond
% appel depuis le document par : \setbeamertemplate{background}{\titrefemto}
\newcommand{\titrefemto}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %definition du node centre au dimension de la page
    \node[minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth](centre) {};
    % placement des logos en bas à gauche
    \matrix[above right=4mm, ampersand replacement=\&] at (centre.south west){
                \node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics[width=11mm]{logo-UBFC.jpg}}; \&
                \node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics[width=7mm]{logo-UFC.jpg}}; \&
        \node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics[width=6mm]{logo-CNRS.jpg}}; \&
        \node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics[width=13mm]{logo-ENSMM.jpg}}; \&
        \node[anchor=center]{\includegraphics[width=12mm]{logo-UTBM.jpg}}; \\
    };
    %placement des logos en haut à droite
    \node[below left, inner sep=0] at (centre.north east) {\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Hexagones.jpg}};
    %placement des logos en haut à gauche
%   \node[below right=6mm] at (centre.north west) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{Femto-logo_couleur-2012.png}};
    \node[below right=6mm] at (centre.north west) {\includegraphics[width=2.8cm]{logo-FEMTO.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

% commande permettant de dessiner une page de fond
% appel depuis le document par : \setbeamertemplate{background}{\pagefemto}
\newcommand{\pagefemto}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % definition du node centre au dimension de la page
    \node[minimum height=\paperheight, minimum width=\paperwidth](centre) {};
    % placement des logos en bas à gauche
%   \node[above right=3mm] at (centre.south west) {\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{Femto-logo_couleur-2012.png}};
    \node[above right=0.75mm] at ([shift={(0.25,0)}]centre.south west) {\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{logo-FEMTO.jpg}};
    %placement des logos en haut à droite
    \node[below left, inner sep=0](hexa) at (centre.north east) {\includegraphics[width=3.9cm]{Hexagones.jpg}};
    %trace des traits
    \coordinate (A) at ([shift={(0.5,-1.4)}]centre.north west);
    \coordinate (B) at (A-| hexa.west);
    \draw[BleuFemtoTitre] (A) -- ([xshift=-3mm]B);
    %trait inferieur
%   \coordinate (A) at ([shift={(0.5,1.1)}]centre.south west);
    \coordinate (A) at ([shift={(0.5,.8)}]centre.south west);
%   \coordinate (B) at ([shift={(-0.5,1.1)}]centre.south east);
    \coordinate (B) at ([shift={(-0.5,.8)}]centre.south east);
    \draw[BleuFemtoTitre] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}


\definecolor{DarkGray}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.80} % PANTONE COOL-GRAY-8


% ajout des couleurs Femto
\definecolor{BleuFemtoTitre}{cmyk}{0.94,0.83,0,0.01}
\definecolor{BleuFemtoTexte}{cmyk}{0.92,0.54,0.05,0.09}
\definecolor{BleuFemto}{RGB}{39,84,148}
\definecolor{BleuClairFemto}{RGB}{66,153,214}
\definecolor{VertFemto}{RGB}{175,203,81}
\definecolor{GrisClairFemto}{RGB}{177,179,180}
\definecolor{GrisFemto}{RGB}{112,127,135}

\usetheme{default}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=DarkGray}

% _                       _       _         _   _ _            
%| |_ ___ _ __ ___  _ __ | | __ _| |_ ___  | |_(_) |_ _ __ ___ 
%| __/ _ \ '_ ` _ \| '_ \| |/ _` | __/ _ \ | __| | __| '__/ _ \
%| ||  __/ | | | | | |_) | | (_| | ||  __/ | |_| | |_| | |  __/
% \__\___|_| |_| |_| .__/|_|\__,_|\__\___|  \__|_|\__|_|  \___|
%                  |_|                                         

%\pgfdeclareimage[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{titrefemto}{TitreFemto.png}

\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
\vskip 10mm 
\usebeamerfont{title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{title}\LARGE\textcolor{BleuFemto}\inserttitle
\newline\newline
\normalsize\textcolor{GrisFemto}\insertauthor
\newline
\vskip 1mm
\textcolor{GrisFemto}\insertinstitute
\newline\newline
\footnotesize\textcolor{GrisFemto}\insertdate
}

% _                       _       _                                
%| |_ ___ _ __ ___  _ __ | | __ _| |_ ___   _ __   __ _  __ _  ___ 
%| __/ _ \ '_ ` _ \| '_ \| |/ _` | __/ _ \ | '_ \ / _` |/ _` |/ _ \
%| ||  __/ | | | | | |_) | | (_| | ||  __/ | |_) | (_| | (_| |  __/
% \__\___|_| |_| |_| .__/|_|\__,_|\__\___| | .__/ \__,_|\__, |\___|
%                  |_|                     |_|          |___/      

%\pgfdeclareimage[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{pagefemto}{PageFemto.png}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vspace{6mm}\hspace{-5mm}\Large\bf\textcolor{BleuFemto} \insertframetitle}

% pour les block
\definecolor{fondFemtotableau}{rgb}{1,0.71,0.754}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=BleuClairFemto!60,bg=BleuFemto}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=GrisClairFemto!40,fg=GrisFemto!50!black}
\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=gray}
\newenvironment{femtoBlock}[1]{%
  \textcolor{BleuFemto}{\normalsize\textbf{#1}}\normalsize}
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}
{%
  \leavevmode%
  \vspace{-2mm}%
  \hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.85\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=-2.5ex,leftskip=.3cm plus1fill,rightskip=.3cm]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot} \hfill \textcolor{GrisFemto}{\insertshortinstitute}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.15\paperwidth,right,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.8ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot} \hfill \textcolor{BleuFemto}{\insertframenumber\ / \inserttotalframenumber}\hspace{0.25cm}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip 10pt%
}

\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}[circle]
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}[circle]

\partopsep=0ex % espace apres les blocks et avant le contenu
\topsep=5ex % debut du texte du slide
\parsep=0ex
\itemsep=0ex
```

## Here is the main part needed to change

```
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{\leavevmode
 \vspace{-2mm}
 \useoutertheme[subsection=false]{smoothbars}}
```

I am not sur of these commands...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Your question is currently very difficult to answer. Firstly it is not fully clear to me what you mean with a "smooth bar", do you mean rounded corners? Or a shadow? Or the top bar with the dots itself? Secondly, without seeing your code it is very difficult to guess what you need to add and where. So to improve your question it would be good if you add your own code to the question, in such a way that it can be compiled.

Comment: I would like to add the top bar with the dots itself not in the first page of the presentation byt in the rest of the diapositives. The rest is already done. I will ass the sty folder created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\geometry{paperheight=2in,paperwidth=3in}
\author{The author}
\title{The title}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars} 
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
    \maketitle
\end{frame}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{baz}Hello\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{baz}Word\end{frame}
\end{document}
```